# Using a variable to access a list field

Tags: c#, variables, reflection, field

Is it possible to use a variable to access a List field  using c# as in the following?

```
string myField = "ImmediateAddress";
byte returnByte = mnemonicList[0].myField;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: And what type is `mnemonicList`?

Comment: "Yes, but not very efficiently" (unless the type exposes a keyed API)

Comment: mnemonicList is a list of class Mnemonics.  What I am trying to do is refactor my code  from six method calls to a single method.  Each method performs the same result with the exception of the lookup in the list.  i.e. returnByte in my snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using reflection you can access fields at run time, and don't forget to add validations

```
mnemonicList[0].GetType().GetProperty(myField).GetValue(mnemonicList[0], null);
```

Comment: Hmmmm, Thought I had this but when it tried to return an int field within my list it doesn't work.  Seems that the GetProperty(myField) wants a string.  I have tried casting myField to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is much help - but instead of a `List`, you could use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Let me know if I'm suggesting the wrong solution, but this way you can access entries with objects like string, like `dictObject["keyToValue"]`. It does require you to use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`, but if you want to do find things with a string, it's the easiest solution.